# Obtaining ID of containing resource via params[:id] for custom actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following routes in my `config/routes.rb` file:

```
resources :employees do
  get 'dashboard'
  get 'orientation'
end
```

`employees` refers to a regular resource handling the standard RESTful actions. `dashboard` and `orientation` are what I currently refer to "custom actions" which act on `Employee` instances. I apologize if I have my terminology mixed up and `dashboard` and `orientation` are really something else. These custom actions respond to URLs as follows:

```
http://myhost/employees/1/dashboard
```

i.e. They're "member" actions much like `show`, `edit` etc.

Anyway, this all works well enough. Regular actions such as `show` on `EmployeesController` obtain the ID of the associated `Employee` through `params[:id]`. However, with this current structure, `dashboard` and `orientation` have to use `params[:employee_id]` instead. This is not too difficult to deal with, but does lead to some additional code complexity as my regular `before_filter`s which expect `params[:id]` don't work for these two actions.

How do I have the routing system populate `params[:id]` with the ID for these custom actions in the same way as `show` etc.? I've tried various approaches with `member` instead of `get` for these actions but haven't got anything to work the way I would like yet. This app is built using Ruby on Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

```
resources :employees do
  member do
    get 'dashboard'
    get 'orientation'
  end
end
```

and the above will generate routes like below, and then you will be able to use params[:id] in your EmployeesController.

```
dashboard_employee   GET    /employees/:id/dashboard(.:format)          employees#dashboard
orientation_employee GET    /employees/:id/orientation(.:format)        employees#orientation
```

Comment: Thanks, Kuldeep. I will try this tonight and let you know if it works.

Comment: No Problem Richard. :)

Comment: One other comment: my approach had the advantage that the resulting path methods `employee_dashboard_path` and `employee_orientation_path` follow standard English word order (noun modifier followed by noun) whereas yours are noun followed by noun modifier. I suppose this is because I'm violating the Rails convention that actions should be verbs. Do you know of any way to specify the helper method name?

Comment: Sorry Richard, don't have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this example, but you can set the resourceful paths explicitly.

Something like this might work:

```
resources :employees, path: '/employees/:id' do
  get 'dashboard', path: '/dashboard'
  get 'orientation', path: '/orientation'
end
```